# How to fix “Operation not supported” on mac os

Tags: macos, terminal, unix, external-hard-drive, macos-catalina

I am trying to install the Flutter onto my computer onto an external drive I have followed the instructions on their website to try and install it. https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos. I can download it then unzip it, but when I try and run any flutter command it gives me an "Operation not supported" error infinite amount of times.

I have tried to install it on my desktop and it worked just fine. The problem is something with the external hard drive. The directory I have tried to install flutter in is /Volumes/RAVPOWER/Devins_Macbook/flutter_development I have added this to my paths folder, I have also tried adding it to .bash_profile. When I run the echo command it shows me exactly where the path to flutter is flutter_development/flutter/bin.

I have also tried changing the permissions for the /Volumes folder I set the users to my name and set it to 777. it has a + at the end of the permissions for the folder I don't know if that makes a difference, but I also don't know how to get rid of it.

I have also set full disk access to terminal first, then I set full disk access to the flutter exec.

I haven't tried running mac in recovery mode because that would only be a temporary fix if I messed with the sip settings and disabled it

I have been dealing with this issue for a while and I'd like to do all my development on this drive as it is the only thing I have space on. any help would be apreciated

```
shlock: link(/Volumes/RAVPOWER/Devins_Macbook/flutter_development/flutter/bin/cache/shlock1241, /Volumes/RAVPOWER/Devins_Macbook/flutter_development/flutter/bin/cache/.upgrade_lock): Operation not supported
```

the number after shlock is how many times its tried to run I am not sure what .upgrade_lock running the ls -al command

```
drwxr-xr-x   8 devintripp  admin    256 Dec 15  2018 Users
drwxrwxrwx+  6 devintripp  wheel    192 Nov  7 20:51 Volumes
```

as you can see the Users has less permissions than the actual drive

The expected results should tell me what I need to install for flutter to work on my computer as flutter doctor should.

Comment: What volume format is the external drive using? Also, I'd recommend against changing permissions -- or much of anything -- on /Volumes; that's much more likely to cause trouble than to fix it.

Comment: I second Gordon. I bet your external drive is using FAT or some other volume format that doesn't support something Flutter is trying to do with lock files. Consider switching to some form of APFS or HFS+ ("Mac OS Extended").

Answer (score 0):

After reading a comment I realized that formatting the drive to Mac OS extended actually fixed the issue that I was having I had some sort of FAT file format, so that I could transfer files between windows and mac.